# Bash variable inside third remote server

Tags: linux, bash, variables, docker

I need to input a variable into third linux system, here is the scheme:

From my laptop > docker server > a container,

```
#!/bin/bash

domain=$1

ssh -i $SSH_KEY docker@10.10.10.10 "docker run --rm=true 931967fb3e32 /bin/bash -c curl -Is $domain
```

Of course the variable reaches only the docker server, but not the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option to test is to pass `$domain` as an [environment variable to your `docker run`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) command:

```
docker run -it --rm -e "domain=$domain" 931967fb3e32 /bin/bash -c curl -Is $domain
```

(note the use of `-it`, to be sure to have a tty in an interactive session)

If the `curl` somehow doesn't pick the right value, (you can test it by replacing `/bin/bash -c curl -Is $domain` with `/bin/bash -c echo $domain`), wrap it in a script (which mean your image should include that script)

As discussed in the comments, it seems to work without the `bash -c`:

```
ssh -i $SSH_KEY docker@10.10.10.10 "docker run --rm=true 931967fb3e32 curl -Is $domain
```

Comment: I`m not logged in the docker server via tty so i cannot start the container with tty. Also tested with the echo on the container and its blank.

Comment: @SScast that could be because of the lack of tty (unless a simple `echo xxx` does display `xxx`). Can you also try without the `bash -c`? (just to test, although it will depend on the `ENTRYPOINT` of your image)

Comment: Thank you VonC, without the bash it works but now it turns on that we need to execute another command after the curl, its echo in the hosts file, so we need the bash option

Comment: @SScast do you confirm that you needed the `-e "domain=$domain"` option?

Comment: @SScast OK. I have edited the answer to put the command that works. Can you review it?